# Dynamically set v-for with vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

So I'm using Vue.js in my project, and I've got a problem: how could I bind filter for `v-for` dynamically? At some moment of time I'm passing the id of element to the vue method, how could I then put it into `v-for item in items | filterBy @{id} in 'id'`?

I've tried just putting '`v-for`' attribute by JQuery '`attr`', but this does not seem to work. I suppose that `Vue.filter` or `vm.$set` should be used here, but I can't figure anything out yet.

Would appreciate any possible help!

For example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  ...
  methods: {
    bindId: function(id) { //id is passed from html
      var repeat = 'item in items | filterBy "' + id + '" in "id"';
      $(#main).children('.collection').attr('v-for', repeat);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: well for now I've just put each() function, comparing ids and making $(this).remove if they are not equal. This looks horrible, but at least works

Comment: Are you getting the id from the same html page or from an external html resource? your markup would be helpful

Comment: from the same html (but in html it gets loaded from database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a variable in your `v-for` attribute:

```
v-for item in items | filterBy id in 'id'

var vm = new Vue({
  ...
  data:function() {
    return {
      id:1
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could use `v-model` on an input like text or select, and set the id there:

```
<input v-model="id"> <!-- Filter to the id inputted here  -->
```

A few examples here: **https://vuejs.org/api/#filterBy**

Comment: is it possible to set data inside another vue method?

Comment: yes, you can just do `this.id = foo` or use `this.$set('id',foo)`

Comment: thanks, I shall try this, sounds like it should work